# Why did my current navigation libraries and lists disappear?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, current-navigation

Under Site Settings>Navigation, I incorrectly checked the Show subsites box under Current Navigation. This enabled a link to all subsites in my left pane (which I did not want). Instead of going back to the Navigation settings (which probably would have avoided this issue), I clicked Edit Links from my main site and was able to hide the subsites (but not remove them, which I was fine with).

The only problem was that after I clicked Save, SharePoint deleted all of the other current navigation links that we had to our team site libraries and lists. **Can someone please explain why it removed those links?** Nothing was changed accept to Show subsites in that pane and nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the SharePoint Online issue, it not occurs in my SharePoint 2013/2016 environment.

If you want to hide the sub sites in current navigation, we can go to  Site Settings>Navigation>Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting, and show or hide subsites links in here.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'm still not sure why it removed my original libraries though. I saw that I could hide the subsites (which i did). I ended up just unchecking the box for including subsites because i can't see a use for them there. I just thought it was very curious that by including the subsites, it would remove the original links that were there just from editing he links on the left pane.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in SharePoint Online, you can submit a feedback for the SharePoint Online to get more helps.

Comment: Having thought this through more, whatever I changed must have overwritten what I had before. Still strange and very annoying.